# Iterating over .csv files and naming dataframes respectively

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

how can I iterate over .csv files in a folder, create dataframe from each .csv and name those dateframes after respective .csv files. Or it could be actually any other name.

My approach doesnt event create a single dataframe.

```
path = "/user/Home/Data/"

files = os.listdir(path) 

os.chdir(path)

for file, j in zip(files, range(len(files))):
     if file.endswith('.csv'):
        files[j] = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using glob? this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe) might help with what you're trying to do

Comment: if you want to access dataframes by name, consider adding them to a dictionary. FWIW you can use `for index, filename in enumerate(files)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pathlib and a dictionary to do that (as already pointed out by jitusj in the comment).

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(".../user/Home/Data/") # complete path needed! Replace "..." with full path

dict_of_df = {}
for file in path.glob('*.csv'):
    dict_of_df[file.stem] = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Now you have a dictionary of dataframes, with the filenames as keys (without .csv extension).